# Loading a Silverlight website in a WebFrame when built for 32-bit Intel Architecture

Tags: silverlight, cocoa, webkit, webview, 32bit-64bit

I am using a `WebFrame` to load a request to a website that is running Microsoft SilverLight.  When I build my application using the 64-bit Intel architecture (x86_64), it runs fine.  However, because I must use a third party library built for 32-bit Intel, I must build my application using that architecture.  When I do that, I get the following error message

```
<Error>: clip: empty path.
```

prior to a second call to

```
- (void) webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame
```

and my application eventually crashes or hangs.

Has anyone experienced this problem and know what the issue may be?  Is there some reason why this only happens when building for the 32-bit Intel architecture?

For what it's worth, here is a stack trace of the crash:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x000000007cabac94

VM Regions Near 0x7cabac94:
  MALLOC_TINY            000000007c800000-000000007ca00000 [ 2048K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--> MALLOC_TINY            000000007ca00000-000000007cb00000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=COW  
   MALLOC_TINY            000000007cb00000-000000007cc00000 [ 1024K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  

Application Specific Information:
objc[44662]: garbage collection is OFF

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   ???                             0x7cabac94 0 + 2091625620
1   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0aaea95e GetCLRRuntimeHost + 220078
2   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0aa2c23e MetaDataGetDispenser + 1383214
3   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0ad799e3 PAL_InitializeCoreCLR + 57795
4   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0aa2b1c5 MetaDataGetDispenser + 1378997
5   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0aa2b49f MetaDataGetDispenser + 1379727
6   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0aa2b60b MetaDataGetDispenser + 1380091
7   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0aab3630 MetaDataGetDispenser + 1937184
8   com.microsoft.net.coreclr       0x0aab4f67 GetCLRRuntimeHost + 439
9   com.microsoft.SilverlightPlugin 0x09499a57 UI_GetSaveFileName + 37895
10  com.microsoft.SilverlightPlugin 0x093e5858 ippiDCTQuantInv8x8LS_JPEG_16s8u_C1R_SSE +    4824
11  com.microsoft.SilverlightPlugin 0x08cb7dc1 main + 769249
12  com.microsoft.SilverlightPlugin 0x09480ad7 LocalMessageReceive + 308343
13  com.microsoft.SilverlightPlugin 0x092789a1 PopupRoot_GetOpenPopups + 427361
14  com.microsoft.SilverlightPlugin 0x09273a65 PopupRoot_GetOpenPopups + 407077
15  com.microsoft.SilverlightPlugin 0x0925d8a6 PopupRoot_GetOpenPopups + 316518
16  com.microsoft.SilverlightPlugin 0x0925db19 PopupRoot_GetOpenPopups + 317145
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c8667be    __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c8666fd __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 413
19  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c838917 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 375
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x9c838798 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 120
21  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97b91a7f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 318
22  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97b98d9b ReceiveNextEventCommon + 381
23  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x97b98c0a BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 88
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x9b358040 _DPSNextEvent + 678
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x9b3578ab -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 113
26  com.apple.AppKit                0x9b353c22 -[NSApplication run] + 911
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x9b5e818a NSApplicationMain + 1054
28  com.Vigience.TestBrowser        0x0009be09 start + 53
```

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you are getting hit by issue 1 that I outlined in my answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205081/webview-crashes-when-rendering-silverlight-site/13018565#13018565). I see that you are not using Mono, but you are using webView, and the crash stack looks very similar. In similar cases, a number of us have had luck with changing the useragent string...

Comment: Hmmm.. very interesting.  They do indeed look very similar. I'm no longer working on this project, but if I was, I'd certainly give that a try.  It certainly could be the issue.  Thanks for posting it!

Comment: No problem. It could also very easily be issue 2 as well (or both :-P) - SL + Mac = blech :-/