# Linking a 32-bit shared library with Intel 64-bit architecture (x86_64) on MacOSX

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, shared-libraries, 32bit-64bit

I have a 32-bit shared library that I need to link with my application (a 64-bit version is apparently not available, and I do not have the source code to rebuild it).  However, I must build my application using 64-bit architecture due to a bug I've encountered with the Silverlight plugin when building for 32-bit architecture.  The details of this bug can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120863/loading-a-silverlight-website-in-a-webframe-when-built-for-32-bit-intel-architec)

Needless to say, I get the following linker warning

```
ld: warning: ignoring file xxx.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

So is there any way to link a 32-bit shared library when building for the 64-bit architecture?

Comment: Maybe this can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943681/linking-32-bit-library-to-64-bit-program

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not. 32-bit code and 64-bit code are fundamentally incompatible with one another; there is no way to link a 64-bit binary to a 32-bit library or vice versa.